# Properties file not updating

Tags: java, eclipse, properties

I have a Properties file wherein my connection params are saved.
There were changes with the username and it happened that I need to change the Properties file.

I edited the file but does not reflect the changes in the program so I have to manually set the values.

Before:

```
username=exakt
```

After:

```
username=exakt123
```

But the exakt123 is not reflected in the program although I have edited the properties file.

Thanks in advance!

This is how I load the properties file.

```
if(file.exists()){
                sqlConfig.load(new FileInputStream(file));
            }else{
                sqlConfig.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().
                            getResourceAsStream("config/ora.config.properties"));
            }
```

Comment: can u show some code? how u are updating it.

Comment: i updated directly the properties file. modifying the username. and when I print out the username param, the before value is still dislayed

Comment: u need to close the Property filestream and open it again. (possibly just re-calling load will also do)

Comment: @ay89, I included the code, how I load the properties file

Comment: I used this code. And BOOM. It worked   FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
   sqlConfig.setProperty("password", "exakt123");
   sqlConfig.store(output, null);

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop current running job and restart the job, then only your new properties will effect.

Comment: How to stop the current job?

Comment: How are you running the job? Are you using any tool? else you can kill java from task manager to stop the job.

Answer (score 0):

You have to reload the properties file again

Comment: I am reloading the properties file every time the class is called. I have included my code in loading the properties file